# React updating state after User control value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting a book list from database and is stored in a state variable
Book list also has book price field

```
const [books, setBooks]=useState([])

setBooks(data)
```

I am creating an html in a loop based on this data

```
return ( <div>
{books.map((x,i) => ( <tr>
                         <td>x.bookName</td>
                         <td><MyCustomTextInput value={x.price}></MyCustomTextInput></td>
                      <tr></div>);
```

Following is the implementation of MyCustomTextInput

```
function MyCustomTextInput(props)
     { return (<div>><MyCustomTextInput></MyCustomTextInput> </div>) 
     } exports default MyCustomTextInput
```

My question is: when I change a price in the custom text input appeared in the table, it does not change in the underlying state level variable's array element

Could you please suggest?

Comment: please show MyCustomTextInput

Comment: here is the pseudo code of MyCustomTextInput

function MyCustomTextInput(props){

return (<div>><MyCustomTextInput></MyCustomTextInput> </div>)
}
exports default MyCustomTextInput

Comment: i don't understand how MyCustomTextInput contain MyCustomTextInput?

Comment: oh apologize, please read following

function MyCustomTextInput(props)
     { return (<div>><TextInput></TextInput> </div>) 
     } exports default MyCustomTextInput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change a price in books state update books state like that

```js
const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    setBooks(books => books.map(book => {
        if (book.id === id) book.price = e.target.value;
        return book;
    }))
};

//you must pass onChange prop to Input
<MyCustomTextInput onChange={e => handleChange(e, x.id)} value={x.price}>

//pass onChange prop to Input like this
function MyCustomTextInput(props){ 
   return <TextInput onChange={props.onChange}/>
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed for your response. Looking at the code I can see it may fix the issue. I will accept it as an answer shortly.

Comment: Ahmed:

Following is MyCustomTextInput sample. The "onChange" event in the code fragment you have provided is not getting triggered.




here is the pseudo code of MyCustomTextInput

function MyCustomTextInput(props){

return (<div>><MyCustomTextInput></MyCustomTextInput> </div>)
}
exports default MyCustomTextInput


Any thoughts on why the onChange is not getting triggered?

Comment: MyCustomTextInput is created as a functional component and I do not have added "extends Component" is this the reason "onChange" event is not getting triggered?

If yes, then what is the way to do so?

Comment: pass onChange to input inside MyCustomTextInput  or share MyCustomTextInput code

Comment: I have added the code for MyCustomTextInput , please see the comments or the post

Comment: Thank you, accepting as an answer. I have another question which I will post in another thread.

Comment: Could you please have a look at another question which is related to this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703450/react-updating-state-after-user-control-value-changes-handling-onchange-inside